# Cannot create a map using folium

Tags: python, dictionary, web-applications, folium

The code I run:

```py
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09],
                 zoom_start=6,
                 tiles="Mapbox Bright")
map.save("Map1.html")
```

I saved it as `map1.py` and ran it with Visual Studio Code
 
The error I get:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:/development/Python/Python/35-web-app/map1.py", line 2, in <module>
        map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")
      File "C:\Users\hirusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 288, in __init__
        tile_layer = TileLayer(tiles=tiles, attr=attr,
      File "C:\Users\hirusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\folium\raster_layers.py", line 95, in __init__
        raise ValueError(
    ValueError: Built-in templates for Mapbox and Cloudmade have been removed. You can still use these providers by passing a URL to the `tiles` argument. See the documentation of the `TileLayer` class.
```

What can I go? Does it have to do something with my code? why isn't this working?

Comment: What does the documentation say about passing a URL to the `tiles` argument. See the documentation of the `TileLayer` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `tiles="Mapbox Bright"` anymore since built-in templates for Mapbox and Cloudmade have been removed.

Here is the documentation https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html
`Ctrl+F` and look for `class folium.raster_layers.TileLayer` for further information

Find similar discussion at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/using-mapbox-tiles-with-folium

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the `TileLayer` class, replacing `tiles="Mapbox Bright"` by `tiles="Stamen Terrain"` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "Mapbox Bright" by "Stamen Terrain"

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.